# List order manipulating in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two python lists as follow:

```
ListA = [a1,a2,a1,a3,a2,a4,a5,a4]
ListB = [b1,b2,b1,b3,b2,b4,b5,b4]
```

What I want is to find the equal elements in the two lists and print them in a file. I have found the equal elements in lists and add them to two new lists as follow:

```
[a1,a2,a4]
[b1,b2,b4]
```

I want to compare some parameters with elements in ListA and if an element in ListA and the parameter is equal print the corresponding element in ListB. I do this as follow.

```
for i,j in enumerate(ListA):
    if j == paramname:
        filelines.append('%sTransferSourceName = "%s"\n'%(indent,ListB[i]))
```

My problem is that the element are not in the order for ListB. It is added like below:

```
b2,b4,b1
```

So the whole order get mixed up.
Note that the number of letters in each element in the lists may differ.

Here is the code I have done so far:

> def ProcessLinks():

```
duplicates = [x for x in linkparamArray if linkparamArray.count(x) > 1]

linkstemp = list(set(duplicates))
for i in linkstemp:

    links.append(i)
```

def ProcessLinks2():

```
duplicates2 = [x for x in linkparameterArray if linkparameterArray.count(x) > 1]

linkstemp2 = list(set(duplicates2))
for j in linkstemp2:

    linkparameters.append(j)
```

And here is the comparing code:

paramname = a1

> for i,j in zip(linkparameters,links):

```
                if i == paramname:
                    filelines.append('%s         TransferSourceName = "%s"\n(indent,j))
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear to me, but I think you could benefit from using the `zip` method for your loop, like `for a,b in zip(ListA, ListB):`

Comment: I get the values in the second list mixed up and not the one relavent to elements in first list, eg: a1,b2 a2,b4, a4,b1  But I want the values in the two list to come as, a1,b1  a2,b2 a4,b4  Zip method did not help me with that. :( thanks.

Comment: It would help if you included an entire code snippet that we could run. As it is, it is unclear what "paramname" is, and what you are expecting to get out.

Comment: Hi david, I have added the code I did so far. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to determine duplicate elements.

```
>>> ListA = ['a1','a2','a1','a3','a2','a4','a5','a4']
>>> ListB = ['b1','b2','b1','b3','b2','b4','b5','b4']
>>> cB=collections.Counter(ListB)
>>> cA=x=collections.Counter(ListA)
>>> [i for i in cA if cA[i]>1]
['a1', 'a2', 'a4']
>>> [i for i in cB if cB[i]>1]
['b4', 'b1', 'b2']
```

As per the Comment of OP as the order is important than the following solution might work using (OrderedDict)[http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict]

```
dB=collections.OrderedDict()
dA=collections.OrderedDict()
>>> for a in ListB:
    dB.setdefault(a,0)
    dB[b]+=1

>>> for b in ListB:
    dB.setdefault(b,0)
    dB[b]+=1

>>> [i for i in dA if dA[i]>1]
['a1', 'a2', 'a4']
>>> [i for i in dB if dB[i]>1]
['b1', 'b2', 'b4']
```

Comment: How can I use collections? I tried to add it, but getting an error as "unresolved symbol." Can I download it and add?

Comment: @gishu, What python version you are using? OrderedDict was new in Version 2.7. You can just use it by importing as `import collections`

Comment: Thanks Abhijit. It solved the problem and the second list comes in order now.

Answer (score 0):

By 'equal elements' do you mean repeated elements?

What is 'indent'?

The problem with using a dictionary is that you cannot have keys that are repeated. So if you were to build a dictionary using the two lists, the dictionary will contain only one entry (key, value pair) for each element in a list that is repeated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ambidextrous. Yes, the equal elements mean the repeated elements. I want to find the repeated ones in both lists and add them in the order such that ListA's and ListB's i th element shall be a1 and b1.

Comment: And  the indent is just an "" defined earlier, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: This wasn't really an answer, so it is best to post these as comments.